# Vertical navigation bar issue (Diagonal bar)

Tags: css, responsive

Currently working on a website for a client, who wants a custom navigation bar, which aligns with a background image.

A working solution is as below:

[image]

The issue I have is that when the browser is resized/certain desktop monitors, the navigation bar does not align with the background. The reason for this is I have coded in pixel values and not made it properly responsive yet, which is where i'm currently stuck. Could anyone guide me on how to make the angles change depending on the browser size/viewport in order to achieve the alignment i require across all desktop/tablet devices?

Can provide the code as required, the navigation bar is just a vertical menu with margin-lefts though.

```html
    .nav {margin:0; position: fixed; z-index: 9999999; left:734px; top: 79px; width: 200px;}
.nav ul {}
.nav ul li {list-style: none; border-bottom:1px solid #7c818c; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top:11px; width:170px;  font-size: 14px;}
.nav ul li:nth-child(2) {margin-left:27px;}
.nav ul li:nth-child(3) {margin-left:55px;}
.nav ul li:nth-child(4) {margin-left:87px;}
.nav ul li:nth-child(5) {margin-left:118px;}
.nav ul li:nth-child(6) {margin-left:146px;}
.nav ul li:nth-child(7) {margin-left:180px;}
.nav ul li:nth-child(8) {margin-left:205px;}
.nav ul li:nth-child(9) {margin-left:235px;}
.nav ul li a {color: #7c818c; text-decoration: none;/* text-transform: uppercase;*/}
.nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a.active {color: #fff;}
```

Comment: Yes, always provide the code

Comment: So, the corners of the bar have to match the corners of the screen? Sounds like it would need some trigonometry, unless there's a library for that kind of bar.

Comment: Don't post without code and expected/actual results, as otherwise the question is liable to be flagged as having insufficient info.

Comment: Hi, have added the code, however it is just a manual method of displaying the navigation list, i need it to be aligned to the background image for all screen resolutions.